# change seconds in dataframe index

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I got a pandas dataframe where the index is a timestamp like

```
"2020-03-14 05:02:06+04:00" or "2020-03-14 08:34:27+04:00"
```

I want all seconds to be 00, that is :

```
"2020-03-14 05:02:06+04:00"  -->  "2020-03-14 05:02:00+04:00" 

"2020-03-14 08:34:27+04:00"  -->  "2020-03-14 08:34:00+04:00"
```

is there a convenient way of not involving building a new column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DatetimeIndex.floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.floor.html) by minutes:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2]}, index= ['2020-03-14 05:02:06+04:00',
                                       '2020-03-14 08:34:27+04:00'])

df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
df.index = df.index.floor('Min')
print (df)
                           a
2020-03-14 05:02:00+04:00  1
2020-03-14 08:34:00+04:00  2
```